# Specflow overwriting original exception stack trace

Tags: c#, specflow, functional-testing

Do any of you know a workaround that would turn off the behaviour mentioned in the title? Each time I do something wrong in my test steps, the exception looks like below:

```
Test method 
FunctionalTests.Features.Parties.PartyAddingFeature.FeatureTitle threw exception: 
TechTalk.SpecFlow.BindingException: Error calling binding method 'FunctionalTests:FunctionalTests.Steps.PartiesSteps.GivenLegacyPartyUpsertedIntegrationEventCameInWithData(String, Table)': Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.
    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Bindings\BindingInvoker.cs:line 69
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 395
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 316
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep() in D:\a\1\s\TechTalk.SpecFlow\Infrastructure\TestExecutionEngine.cs:line 132
   at FunctionalTests.Features.Parties.PartyAddingFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
   at FunctionalTests.Features.Parties.PartyAddingFeature.FeatureTitle() in C:\Project\test\Services\FunctionalTests\Features\Parties\PartyAdding.feature:line 25
```

Comment: Could you post the scenario and the binding where this happens? I think this error has more to to with converting the parameters as with an error within the step.

Comment: It has a whole lot to do with converting parameters, but that's not the question here :) The problem is that my step contains couple places where I do a conversion (or should do one) but the problem is the stack trace is not pointing at a specific location, which means that specflow framework has swallowed the original exception and overwrote it with it's own stack trace. I'm looking for a way to make those stack traces as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

By your opinion, what should be correct exception for this situation? 
I mean, we don’t see or know your code. And by stack trace you posted, it indicates that you have situation with parameter conversion before entering one of Given/when/then method.

Comment: Correct STACK TRACE should be pointing to the place in code where the exception actually occurs, right? And it's pointing to some `BindingInvoker` method which is halfway to the right place :)

Comment: It's really easy to reproduce. Just throw an exception somewhere in your step - you won't see the complete stack trace there, but one similar to mine, and the small difference will be your step's name and exception message.